# Ruby on rails testing custom message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

I  wrote this test:

```
  test "email validation should accept valid address" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@eee.com R_RDD@adf.com user@gmail.com hi12@hi.co a]
    valid_addresses.each do |e|
      @chef.email = e
      assert @chef.valid?, '#{e.inspect} should be valid'
    end
  end
```

When I do rake test, the message when fail is

```
1) Failure:
ChefTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_address [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/chef_test.rb:56]:
#{e.inspect} should be valid

20 runs, 23 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Instead of whatever |e| should be...
I want to see something like "a" should be a valid like a more descriptive message to see the variable and inspect method value.
Pleas help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string *interpolation*. Which can be made using `""`, not `''`.

```
assert @chef.valid?, "'#{e.inspect}' should be valid"
```

You don't need `e.inspect`, only `e` is enough. Like:

```
assert @chef.valid?, "'#{e}' should be valid"
```

One more suggestion is, you can use instance of the class [`ActiveModel::Errors`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors-errors) containing all errors :

```
assert @chef.valid?, @chef.errors[:email]
```